# Identify the Content Carousel

Tags: carousel

Can anybody identify the carousel used on [this site](http://www.grohe.com/uk/)? It seems to work seamlessly with responsive sites and would with little css changes suit my design perfectly. The source shows something called anchorScroll.js but a search comes up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom solution and not a plugin. Look for `Application_NewsSpinner` in http://cdn12.grohe.com/application/resources/javascript/scripts/common.js at line :1072

**But don't steal code!** It's fine to get inspired but you should find your own solution or take an official plugin! Take a look at http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow or http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if it was an official plugin or a custom solution, wouldn't think of stealing code.